# Is enumeration of spanning trees equivalent to probabilistic graph connectivity?

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Let $G$ denote any finite, simple, connected graph with edge set $E(G)$, and let $ t(G)$ denote the number of spanning trees in $G$. Given some probability $p$, consider the following question:

> Given a particular $G$, what is the probability that $G$ will remain connected if each edge in $E(G)$ is given the probability $p$ of being included? Denote this probability $p(G)$.

Is the problem of enumerating spanning trees equivalent to this question? That is, does the following relation hold?

$$ p(G) = p^{n-1}t(G)$$

Note that $p^{n-1}$ comes from the probability of an entire spanning tree being included.

**Additional question:**

If so, is this equivalency helpful for solving either question? If it is, how so? If not, why not?

Comment: Your formula for p(G) can easily give a number larger than 1, no? That's a clear indication that it does not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship does not hold generally. Let $G$ be a triangle. We have
$$
p(G) = 3p^2(1-p) + p^3
$$
which is not equal to $3p^2$. This is because the events that spanning trees are remained are not independent.

Comment: How does the lack of independence impact the probability?